# mean of every cell in matrix multiplcation instead of just the sum in python

Tags: python, matrix, mean

I understand that using the numpy of 2 2d array, it will give me the me the matrix multiplication. The following is the example of my code. The elements in each cell of c is the sum of the product, but what I want in each cell is the average, not the sum.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
c = np.dot(np.transpose(a), b)
```

example is cell 1, the value is `(1*1+1*1 = 2)` what I want is `(average of 1*1+1*1)`. How do I do that using numpy?

Comment: What do you mean by the average of `1*1 + 1*1`?

Comment: If you mean the average of `(1*1, 1*1)`, why not divide the resulting matrix by 2? Each value is a sum of two elements.

Comment: That is correct. Since the dot product is the sum of the products and you want the mean divide the dot product by 2.

Comment: That is just my sample array, but the actual array size is different.

a(size) = 8x300
b(size) = 8X355

c(size) = 300X355, but what I want in each cell of c is the average value, not the sum. So, this means I divide each cell by the number of rows to get the average, is that correct? So this means I divide it by 8? Apologies for the noob question.

Comment: That's exactly right. You divide by whatever the shared dimension is between the two arrays, in this case 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is clear to me now. Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the inputs. I have updated the code to get the average of every cell:

```
c = np.dot(np.transpose(a), b)/len(b)
```